# Fixed-width space in math mode that is gobbled at the end of a line

Tags: math-mode, spacing, line-breaking

Consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myspace}{\hspace{3em}}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{left\myspace right}

\begin{document}

1:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin.
$\mycmd$
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, pellentesque tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

2:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin. 
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus $\mycmd$ varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, pellentesque tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

\renewcommand{\myspace}{$\hspace{3em}$}%
3:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin. 
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus $\mycmd$ varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, pellentesque tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

\end{document}
```

The space between `left` and `right` (content in math mode) in paragraph (1) is fixed at `3em`. I want this space gobbled if it lands at the edge of the text block. Paragraph (2) highlights the problem, while paragraph (3) suggests a fix - switch out of math mode, insert the `\hspace` and switch back to math mode.

How can I create a fixed-width space in math mode that is gobbled at the end of a line?

<sub>My actual use-case is for smaller spaces (like `\,`).</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean `\allowbreak`? Which is a wrapper for `\penalty0`; maybe, strict LaTeX code should do `\linebreak[0]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myspace}{\hspace{3em}}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{left\myspace right}

\begin{document}

1:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla 
rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin.
$\mycmd$
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, pellentesque 
tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

2:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla 
rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin. 
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus $\mycmd$ varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, 
pellentesque tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

\renewcommand{\myspace}{\allowbreak\hspace{3em}}%
3:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla 
rutrum urna sit amet sollicitudin. 
Nulla gravida, leo nec finibus $\mycmd$ varius, turpis magna hendrerit mi, 
pellentesque tempus nisi lectus blandit sem. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

TeX won't break at spaces in math mode, but it can at penalties (possibly automatically supplied).

Comment: The last sentence provides the best solution and clue. Thanks!